# postgresql INSERT ... RETURNING query keeps failing?

Tags: postgresql

The error message is kinda vague...  The query below works on one server, but fails on another:

```
INSERT INTO searches (status, uid, datecreated, searchname, options) 
VALUES (0, 1, NOW(), 'TEST', '16') RETURNING sid;
```

And I get this error:

```
Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING"
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query certainly looks right - assuming the field sid does exist (I take it it's a SERIAL field).

Are you sure you're using a PostgreSQL version that has support for RETURNING? You need version 8.2 or newer for this.